# Pull form from shadowbox, and submit it from the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, shadowbox

I have a form in a shadowbox, and when the user clicks the submit button (or a link with an onclick, i don't mind) i want to step in, close the shadowbox, then submit the form data from the parent window.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?  I can't work it out.

Something like this semi-pseudocode...

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(){
  var parent = window.parent;
  parent.Shadowbox.close();
  parent.submit($(this));
}
```

thanks, max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not picky about closing the shadowbox first, you can just use a `target="_parent"` in the form tag.

Comment: ah, that's a great tip, i didn't know that.  Thanks Kevin!  (i'm not picky about closing the shadowbox first as it happens)

Comment: No problem, I just learned that myself and remarked how easy it was :)